# Can I increase the default size of the task pane for a ms-word add-in?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js, word-addins

I've been working on an add-in for Microsoft word for a little while and the way the app is designed the content is a little squished when the add-in first launches. I've tried digging through the MS documentation and the only thing I've found was in the manifest documentation but the requestedwidth does not work for taskpane apps, I tried it anyway and sure enough it didn't work. I also tried just increasing the width of the html elements in my app but that didn't increase the size of the task pane just allowed me to scroll within the task pane. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to change the default width of the task pane.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this programmatically. Please vote or add item to our user voice channel https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

Comment: Link is not available any more

Answer (score 0):

If some aspects of your app require different amounts of space, the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) is an option.

Comment: Link is not available any more